# Entity Framework: Closure state in WHERE expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, expression-trees

When passing an expression tree representing a predicate to the `.Where` method of an `IQueryable` it eventually gets *somehow* translated into SQL when using Entity Framework. I know that the shape of the expression determines what SQL statements are generated. There surely must be lots of special rules.

However, what I can't wrap my head around is the fact that expression trees can have implicit state (i.e. closure state or receiver object fields) and that e.g. a simple `this.SomeProperty` access can reference that state inside the predicate. When I inspect the generated SQL I see that these accesses get replaced by their values. I wonder: **How** and exactly **when** does this translation happen? Also does it work for arbitrarily complex expressions on associated state?

Comment: How - as usual with `ExpressionVisitor`, but with hard and complex logic. All I can say is that accessors are identified by `MemberExpression` type expressions. When - basically when someone calls `GetEnumerator`.

Comment: Thanks. Using the EF feels like programming against a black box. At least I couldn't find an official easy-to-read documentation on this topic. What expression constructs are supported, and how are they translated to SQL? It is all trial and error and hoping for the best. ;)

Comment: Exactly:) [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964(v=vs.110).aspx) you can find some information.